# Slurm - running multiple tasks at one node

Tags: multiprocessing, task, slurm, sbatch

Suppose I want to run a program with 100 different input arguments. This is what I would do on my laptop for example:

```
for i in {1..32}
    do
    ./test.sh $i
done
```

where test.sh is just a dummy program

```
#!/bin/bash
name=$(hostname)
touch $1.test
echo $name >> $1.test
echo $name
sleep 5
```

if I run the program it'll take approx. 160sec. I try to run a Slurm job on a cluster 40 nodes with 4 cpus each with my test.slurm:

```
#! /bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --ntasks=4
start=`date +%s`
for i in {1..32}
do
   srun -l -n1 -N1 -c1 ./test.sh $i &
done
wait
end=`date +%s`
runtime=$((end-start))
echo $runtime
```

i get a runtime of 190 seconds instead of the expected ~40 so no multiprocesing but if i specify 2 nodes with --nodes=2 or more than 4 tasks ie a second node has to be allocated i get down to 90 seconds

Comment: `srun` is *interactive*, which means that the command waits for it to finish. If you change it into `sbatch` it should work in parallel. You also then dont have to submit this script anymore with `sbatch`.

Comment: thats why im using the & and wait command i am submitting the test.slurm with sbatch test.slurm

So you are suggesting in running multiple jobs at once? This could be working

Comment: Try using the `--exclusive` option of `srun`. (it has a specific meaning, different from the identically-named `sbatch` option). See the `srun` man page, especially the examples.